# Updating @Published variable of an ObservableObject inside child view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I have a published variable `isLoggedIn` inside a  ObservableObject class as follows:

```
import Combine

class UserAuth: ObservableObject{
    @Published var isLoggedIn: Bool = false
}
```

I want to update this variable to true in a particular view (LoginView). This variable determines what view I show the user depending if the user has logged in or not:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject  var userAuth = UserAuth()
    var body: some View {
        Group{
            if(userAuth.isLoggedIn){
                MainView()
            }else{
                AccountView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because userAuth.isLoggedIn is false (I haven't logged in) AccountView is displayed.

AccountView:

```
struct AccountView: View {
    @State private var toggleSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                self.toggleSheet.toggle()
            }){
                Text("Toggle Modal")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$toggleSheet){
                LoginView()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever the user presses the button the LoginView Modal is shown:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                return self.login()
            }){
                Text("Log in")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }

    func login(){
        // update UserAuth().isLoggedIn to TRUE
    }
}
```

In the LoginView there is a button, the logic I want is for the user to press the button, `login()` gets called and inside that function `userAuth.isLoggedIn` is set to `true`. What would be the best way to implement this ?

I've tried to directly change the value and I get an error along the lines of:

```
Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 41):

Try embedding your code in DispatchQueue.main.async like this:

```
func login(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //update UserAuth().isLoggedIn to TRUE
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that by adding `@ObservedObject  var userAuth = UserAuth()` to `LoginView` and adding  `DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.userAuth.isLoggedIn = true;
        }` to the login function, but wouldn't the expected behavior would be for `ContentView` to render `MainView()` because `userAuth.isLoggedIn` is set to `true` ?

Comment: Try using StateObject instead of ObservedObject in both LoginView and ContentView

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to insert the `UserAuth` object from the `ContentView` into the subviews as an `EnvironmentObject`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userAuth = UserAuth()
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if userAuth.isLoggedIn {
                MainView()
            } else {
                AccountView()
                .environmentObject(userAuth)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now `userAuth` is accessible in `AccountView` and all its subviews (e.g. `LoginView`):

```
struct LoginView: View {
    // Access to the environment object
    @EnvironmentObject private var userAuth: UserAuth

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                return self.login()
            }) {
                Text("Log in")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }

    func login() {
        // Update the value on the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.userAuth.isLoggedIn = true
        }
    }
}
```

It may be necessary to insert the EnvironmentObject into the `LoginView` manually. You can do this by accessing it in the `AccountView` and inserting it in the `LoginView`:

```
struct AccountView: View {
    @State private var toggleSheet = false
    // Access the value, that was inserted in `ContentView`
    @EnvironmentObject private var userAuth: UserAuth

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                self.toggleSheet.toggle()
            }){
                Text("Toggle Modal")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$toggleSheet){
                LoginView()
                // Insert UserAuth object again
                .environmentObject(self.userAuth)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

**Further Reading**
[WWDC 2019 Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/) | [Hacking with Swift Example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views)